# Set active doctrine SQL filter on entityManager instanciation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a big application using ZF2 and Doctrine2 and using the DoctrineORMModule. In the configuration I´ve defined a custom SQL filter.

```
'doctrine' => [
    'configuration' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'filters' => [
                'myFilter' => 'MyNamespace\MyFilter'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

The filter is activated in the `onBootstrap` method.

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $entityManager = $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    $entityManager->getFilters()->enable('myFilter');
}
```

Everything is working as expected, which is nice.
However this code is executed on ALL request, even if I don't need the entity manager at all. This really affects my application performance, because all the heavy doctrine factories will be called (which adds like 100ms on every request).

It would be nice if enabled filters are added only when the EntityManager factory is called.
I'd really like to do someting like this, but this doesn't seem like an implemented feature yet.

```
'doctrine' => [
    'configuration' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'active_filters' => [
                'myFilter'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

As a last resort I could override the `EntityManagerFactory`, but I hope there is a cleaner way.
Any suggestions to make this somehow lazy are welcome.

Comment: Take a look at delegator factories -> http://ocramius.github.io/blog/zend-framework-2-delegator-factories-explained/

Comment: Thank for your comment. This is what I ended up using after doing some more research. It's working perfectly.

Comment: No probs Bram, you might want to answer your question with how you solved it, could help someone else down the line.